# REDIS: List with random access

Tags: redis, ordered-map

What's the best way to keep a large list (e.g. 10K items) in Redis, where I also want to efficiently retrieve items by key.

It seems Redis has no data structure equivalent to Java's OrderedHashMap, which accomplishes this, so maybe it's necessary to maintain a set and a list and ensure they stay in sync.

Comment: One example is something like bookmarks. I want to keep a list of users' bookmarks, but at the same time detect if the user has previously bookmarked a given item. With a regular list, that check would be a O(N) operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sorted set;

Add some bookmarks; use current time for `score` to sort chronologically:

```
> zadd bookmarks 123 "bk1"
> zadd bookmarks 456 "bk2"
> zadd bookmarks 789 "bk3"
> zadd bookmarks 999 "bk4"
```

To get a bookmark, you need the index first:

```
> zrank bookmarks "bk3"
> "3"
```

...then pull the bookmark by index:

```
> zrevrange bookmarks 3 3
> "bk3"
```

If you don't want to use timestamps, you can sort bookmarks lexicographically using "1" for score:

```
> zadd bookmarks 1 "link_xyz"
> zadd bookmarks 1 "link_abc"
> zadd bookmarks 1 "link_foo"

> zrange bookmarks 0 -1

1) "link_abc"
2) "link_foo"
3) "link_xyz"
```

The index lookup is `O(log(n))`, add to that `O(log(n)+1)` to pull a single member by index; better than `O(n)` for lists.

Also, if you add the same bookmark twice, redis automatically replaces the previous member, so you avoid duplicates.

Hope it helps,